# Mesh Flickering Problem

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers

I basically have this "flickering" problem of one of my faces in model. Check this short vid for demo:

[Flickering Mesh](https://youtu.be/CuMOo5W9ZsI)

[image]
[image]

Comment: You have overlapping geometry, duplicate faces, or topology errors in that part of your mesh.

Comment: In future, it is preferable to also have pictures to illustrate your problem. If at some point you delete that youtube video this question will become quite unclear as to what it was about.